# What is the most responsive way to make Javascript function calls listener/keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When using  Javascript in a browser to create lightweight games, where the user may use their keyboard to move/etc, I am wondering if there is a functional difference between the use of:

```
onkeydown="someFunction();"
```

and the use of:

```
addEventListener('keypress', function(e) { e.foo(); });
```

It seems to be useful to prevent the default button behavior with one and respond with the other, so I am wondering if one offers a performance improvement such as response speed, queuing sequential clicks, less likely to generate an error, or other unforeseen benefit that I am not aware of

Comment: You should generally be using the second one.

Comment: Avoiding JS in the markup is best, but not because of performance, I haven't run into very many cases where I ever HAVE to have JS in the markup, this is well said by Brad bellow

Comment: in apps, especially boilerplate, if it's something simple that only needs one call on one element, i've found event attributes easier for a web team to maintain. for complex interaction or re-using the same handler on many elements or on dynmically-created elements, addEventListener is the way to go.

Comment: If both are used, is one given precedence over the other? Or can calls for events be simultaneous?

Answer (score 2):

Speaking generally, one is just an alias of the other. an `on*="jsFunc()"` is just calling the browser's native method of attaching an event for you.

However, it's worth noting it's almost always better to keep the two (markup and javascript) separated as much as possible. With that in mind, stick to binding events within your `<script></script>` tags and keep HTML for the UI element.

Comment: If i attach on via listener and another call for a key event, is one call given precedence over another? will the two negate?

Answer (score 1):

The difference here is you'll only bind one function to onkeydown by using the first approach, while you can bind multiple functions to onkeydown by using the second one.

Answer (score 1):

First off, there is a difference between `keydown` and `keypress`.

From [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html):

**keydown**
Fires when the user depresses a key. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed.

**keypress**
Fires when an actual character is being inserted in, for instance, a text input. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed.

So special keys such as `alt` or `ctrl` do not fire `keypress` events but do fire `keydown` events.

Assuming that the events are equal, then yes they are functionally equivalent since every HTML element in the document is represented in the DOM.

The two main benefits of attaching the event as a property (object.addEventListener...) rather than as an attribute are:

1. Separation of JavaScript and HTML. Imagine if the handler was a lot more complicated - you would have a huge string in your HTML.
2. You can dynamically modify the event attribute of the HTML object using JavaScript. Maybe you want to replace a listener after some user action? Well, you can't really do that with just an HTML event attribute because that's static.

Comment: So if attempting to prevent a default action of a keypress(down=scrolldown, spacebar=pagedown in FF) and then assign a listener for the key press, will I just negate my function?

Answer (score 0):

Defining `onkeydown` or in general `onSomeEvent` is setting an explicit property, so you can only set it once.

Binding an event handler allows you to attach many listeners to the same event.

Comment: Couldn't I still use the DOM to access the attribute and manipulate from there?